# Can't open script as application

Tags: bash, scripts, chmod

I'm trying to install `puush` on my computer, everything works great until I run `chmod +x`.

After that, the script will still only open in `gedit`.

I read through similar questions on this site as well as others and have yet to get the script to execute.  Any help would be great, ty.

Comment: have you tried to **right click this script -> properties -> permission -> allow as a program** .

Comment: yes I checked that as well, forgot to mention that in the op

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure your script header contains `#!/bin/bash`.
2. Right-click on your script and click on *Properties*. In the *Permissions* tab, make sure*Allow executing file as program* is checked.
3. You should have `dconf-editor` installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
4. Configure Nautilus to react on a double-click of a script:

   ```
   dconf-editor
   ```
5. Navigate in dconf-editor through the following items: *org ➤ gnome ➤ nautilus ➤ preferences*
6. On *executable-text-activation* select *launch* from the drop-down menu. This will launch scripts as programs.
7. Close `dconf-editor`.
8. Run your script "as a program" double-clicking it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Thumbs up for the nice answer. :) I took the time to fix the formatting a bit. It is considered a good practice to avoid over-using bold. Please see this meta question for more details: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/

Comment: That seemed to do it.  I still cant get the program to start, but I can now run it as a program at least.  I'll double check my work in a bit and see if I can get it started up.  Thank you much :)

Comment: @Icon, Thanks for the question! :-P

Comment: If solved mark(tick) this as answer! @Icon